# Access Jenkins host drive, beside the job workspace

Tags: jenkins

I would like to share byproducts of one jenkins job, with another one that run after.

I am aware that I can set "use custom workspace", but that would merge the jobs together; which is not what I want. I just need to move few files in a location, that are read by the next job.

So far I can't find out how you actually tell Jenkins jobs to look for a specific folder; since it does not have a concept of file system, beyond what is going on in the job workspace folder.

Is there a way to access the host file system, or declare a shared folder inside jenkins (like in the main workspace folder, which contains all the other jobs?), so I can copy and read files in it, from different jobs?

Where possible I would like to avoid plugins and extras; I would like to use what is included with Jenkins base.

Answer (score 1):

I realize you want to avoid plugins, but the Jenkins-y way to accomplish this is to use the [Copy Artifacts plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin), which does exactly what you want.

There are a variety of problems that you may run into when trying to manage the filesystem yourself. (How do you publish to a common location when running on different build nodes? How do you handle unsuccessful builds?) This solution uses Jenkins to track builds and artifacts. In the absence of a separate artifact repository, its a lot better than trying to manage it yourself.

To use Copy Artifacts:

- As a Post-Build step, choose "Archive Artifacts" in the first job and enter the path(s) to the generated files.
- Then in the second job, add a "Copy Artifacts from another project" build step to grab some or all files marked as artifacts in your first job. (By default, Jenkins will re-create the paths of the generated files in the second job's workspace, which may or may not be what you want, but you can change this behavior.)

Comment: Thanks Dave; I guess there is no other way then....I do not understand why this is not part of the standard Jenkins...rarely you have process that does not depend from each other; and if you have to make multiple simple steps, instead than one enormous step, logic would dictate that you may need to share artifacts.

Comment: @newbiez Jenkins doesn't confine itself to a single build system, so it has to have some flexibility in how it handles artifacts.  For example, the differences between a Maven build and a GNU Make build are enormous.

Comment: @newbiez Jenkins purposely goes out of the way to separate all functionality from the core. This allows all functionality to be a plugin, which can be maintained and updated independently of the core. For example: if "Copy Artifacts" was part of core, and it needed updating, you'd have to download and upgrade your whole Jenkins installation (not something that you'd want if you didn't use that functionality). As a plugin, it's updated independently, and if you don't need it, you don't use it. A lot of plugins are maintained by the original creator anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Configure the Jenkins to run a Maven build, and deploy your artifacts with "mvn clean deploy"  This will push it to an "artifact server" which you probably have, or if not, need to add / configure.

Then in your downstream job, also a Maven job, you configure it to depend on the same artifact that was published in the upstream job.  This will trigger a download of the artifact from the artifact server and make it available to the build.

Comment: @newbiez Yes it can, but that means you'll have to do all the work that Maven would do.  You would need some way of identifying the item, including "revisions" of that item, and some way of identifying the location.  You would also need some way of putting the item in that location, and retrieving the item from that location, preferably across a network.  You would need some way of configuring the receiving project to "grab" the right item.  All of it can be done with any kind of tool or programming language, but some tools already handle the details for you.